# Why is REQUEST_URI being modified?

Tags: php

When I run the following piece of code in req.php:

```
<?php
  echo("Request:\n");
  print_r($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
?>
```

Request:

```
curl "http://localhost/req.php/postcode/14482/city/./country/de/"
```

I get this response:

```
Request:
/req.php/postcode/14482/city/country/de/
```

When I use two dots after /city:

```
Request:
/req.php/postcode/14482/country/de/
```

And with three dots after /city:

```
Request:
/req.php/postcode/14482/city/.../country/de/
```

Why is the REQUEST_URI being modified instead of passed thru untouched ?

Edit: It appears cURL is editing REQUEST_URI - is there any setting in the cURL php library to disable this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is the REQUEST_URI being modified instead of passed thru untouched ?

It isn't. The change to the URL is made by cURL before it goes anywhere near the server. The `./` is never in the request that is sent to the server.

`./` means "the current path segment" so it is redundant. The client (cURL) is normalising it before it makes the request.

You can see this by comparing the response to a request with `curl` to the response when you construct the HTTP request by hand.

## Manually constructed request

```
%  telnet localhost 7007
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /index.php/req.php/postcode/14482/city/./country/de/

HTTP/0.9 200 OK
Date: Wed, 04 Apr 2018 07:53:23 +0000
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.7
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Request:
/index.php/req.php/postcode/14482/city/./country/de/
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

## cURL

```
%  curl http://localhost:7007/index.php/req.php/postcode/14482/city/./country/de/
Request:
/index.php/req.php/postcode/14482/city/country/de/
```